# use jQuery to move the cursor to another field when a certain character is typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text fields in my web page.  The user is supposed to enter two numbers seperated by a hyphen ("-") character.  The numbers may be between 1 and 10 digits each.  I need the cursor to move to the next field when the user presses the hyphen key.

I can easily move the cursor using `$('#txtField2').focus()`.  However, I still have the problem that the hyphen character remains in the first text field.  How can I easily supress the hyphen from appearing in the first text field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<form>
    <input type='text' class='num' />
    <input type='text' class='num' />
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('.num:first').keydown(function (event) {
    // check for hyphen
    if (event.which === 189) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.num').focus();
    }
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nyuszika7H/Ba6Db/)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a simplified html of:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="numOne">Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="numOne" name="numOne" />
        <input type="text" id="numTwo" name="numTwo" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The following should work, or serve as an example:

```
$('#numOne').keypress(
    function(e){
        if (e.which == 45) {
            $(this).next('input:text').focus();
            return false; // prevents the '-' being entered.
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KS2Vk/)

Incidentally, I used `$(this).next('input:text')` rather than an id-based selector to allow for more general application and re-use.

References:

- [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/),
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
$('#input1').keypress(function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 45) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#input2').focus();
  }

});
```

see live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wjNP3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p>Insert Your Number:</p>
  <input type="number" value="" id="first" >
  <input type="number" value="" id="second" >
  <input type="number" value="" id="third" >
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#first").on("keypress", function(){
  if($("#first").val().length == 4){
    $("#second").focus();
  }
})

$("#second").on("keypress", function(){
  if($("#second").val().length == 4){
    $("#third").focus();
  }
})

$("#third").on("keypress", function(){
  if($("#third").val().length == 5){
    $("#submit").focus();
  }
})
```

OR you can check Live DEMO by [CLICK HERE!](https://codepen.io/indeveloper/pen/KOyWNx)

Answer (score 0):

you could "listen" to that character and just focus the other field and prevent it from inputing