# Perfom action of "tab" key onkeyup()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 4 text fields. When i enter a value in first text box cursor should move to next text box. That is  onkeyup() i need to perform action of tab key.
Is there any javascript or jquery for that

Comment: you can call `inp.focus()` on the next one it should go to.

Comment: You can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use jQuery to move the cursor to another field when a certain character is typed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198061/use-jquery-to-move-the-cursor-to-another-field-when-a-certain-character-is-typed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="focus" />
<input type="text" class="focus" />
<input type="text" class="focus" />
<input type="text" class="focus" />
```

JS

```
  $(".focus").keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val() != "")
   {
    $(this).next(".focus").focus();
   }
  });
```